# Image segmentation C#

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a picture with a black background and gray objects and I want to filter out the objects. But the light incidence makes it impossible to just look after a color. It will either filter not the whole object or it will filter as well the background.

If some can give an hint or an example in C# it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

sory because i'm using VB.NET but hope I can help you

```
Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap("Grapes.jpg")
Dim pixelColor As Color = myBitmap.GetPixel(X, Y)
if pixelColor = Color.Black
myBitmap.SetPixel(X, Y, Color.Blue)
```

If in objects have black color. I guess you have to change others way to get the object like save object's area.

Comment: This won't work as OP already stated in his answer, it would remove parts of object, or left behind some background.

Answer (score 0):

Without any example image is hard to guess. But for start you should look into histogram equalization. This method enables to balance the lightning in the image.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Examples) has a nice example of what hist equalization is capable of.